# Update the value of JSON key in oracle

Tags: json, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL Developer & want to update the value of particular key in JSON.

I am using below query:

```
   update M  
  set  OBJECT = json_mergepatch (   
     OBJECT, '{ "$.ABC.DATA.WORKFLOW_STATUS.ABC" : "MONIKA" }' 
   ) WHERE KEY_1 = '121';
```

output: Error report

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "JSON_MERGEPATCH": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Kindly suggest me the right query.

Comment: What is the structure of the original JSON and what is the JSON result you are expecting?

Comment: In my JSON this path (ABC.DATA.WORKFLOW_STATUS.ABC ) exist n want to update the value in this key but it is not supporting JSON_MERGEPATCH

Comment: Please tell us the precise version of your Oracle database - not SQL Developer but the database itself. Everyone who asks a question should do this.

Comment: @StewAshton I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition

Comment: JSON_MERGEPATCH was introduced in version 19c of the Oracle Database. If you try to use it in older versions, you will get an "invalid identifier" message - which you already did.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JSON you are trying to update is structured similar to this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data
AS
    SELECT '121' AS key_1, '{
    "ABC": {
        "WORKFLOW_STATUS": {
            "ABC": "some value",
            "XYZ": 5.23
        },
        "OTHER": "fancy text"
    },
    "DEF": 123
}' AS object_val FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '122' AS key_1, '{
    "ABC": {
        "WORKFLOW_STATUS": {
            "ABC": "other value",
            "XYZ": 2
        },
        "OTHER": "cool text"
    },
    "DEF": 999
}' AS object_val FROM DUAL;
```

The correct syntax to update JSON path **$.ABC.DATA.WORKFLOW_STATUS.ABC** would be something like this:

```sql
UPDATE test_data
   SET object_val = json_mergepatch (object_val, '{"ABC":{"WORKFLOW_STATUS":{"ABC":"MONIKA"}}}')
 WHERE key_1 = '121';
```

Comment: Thanks @E J Egyed  but still I am facing same error.

Comment: What version is your Oracle Database? **JSON_MERGEPATCH** wasn't introduced until 19c.

Comment: I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition

Comment: Then you will not be able to use **JSON_MERGEPATCH** as it is a new feature introduced in 19c

Comment: Thank You @EJ Egyed but today I have got the replacement of  JSON_MERGEPATCH, we can use Regexp_replace in place of JSON_MERGEPATCH & it will work.